# How to get a background image in createBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have been trying to get a background image for the tabbar. I tried using `tabBarComponent` but it hides the tabs under it.

The code that I am using is

```
   export default MainNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Profile:{
            screen: Profile,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                    return <Image source={require('./images/tab_explore.png')} />
                }
            }),
        }
    },

    {
        tabBarComponent: props =>{
            return(
                <View style={{backgroundColor:"black"}}> 
                <Image
                    style={{ width:'100%', height: 80 }}
                    source={ require('./images/bottom_btn.png')} />
                </View>
            );
        }
    })
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

Current Output:
[image]

 
 It should show the tabs on top of orange color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it is too late, but I wish this answer will help many people. In React Navigation version 2 you can do it like this:

`import { createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';`

You don't need to install react-navigation-tabs if you have installed 'react-navigation'.
Then create TabBarComponent by `const TabBarComponent = (props) => (<BottomTabBar {...props} />);`. You will use `tabBarComponent` key in `createBottomTabNavigator`. BackgroundColor: 'transparent' for default tabs and VOILA!

The following code will give you the main idea

```
export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Posters: { 
        screen: Posters,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'AFİŞA',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <MaterialIcons name="local-movies" size={24} color={tintColor} />
            )
        }
    },
    ComingSoon: { 
        screen: ComingSoon,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'TEZLİKLƏ',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <MaterialIcons name="movie" size={24} color={tintColor} />
            )
        }
    },
    Tickets: { 
        screen: Tickets,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'BİLETLƏR',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <MaterialIcons name="confirmation-number" size={24} color={tintColor} />
            ),

        }
    },
    More: { 
        screen: More,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'MENU',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <MaterialIcons name="more-horiz" size={24} color={tintColor} />
            ),
            tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }) => {
                return <Text>sd</Text>
            }
        }
    },


}, 
{
    order: ['Posters', 'ComingSoon', 'Tickets', 'More' ],


    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.darkYellow(),
      inactiveTintColor: 'white',
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontFamily: defaults.fontFamily
      },
      style: styles.tabBar,
    },

    tabBarComponent: props =>{
        return(

            <React.Fragment>
                <TabBarComponent {...props} />
                <Image style={styles.fakeTabBackground}/>
            </React.Fragment>

        )
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I wish I could comment but I don't have enough reputation to do that.

```
<React.Fragment>
 <ImageBackground 
   source={require('./images/bottom_btn.png')} 
   style={{width: '100%', height: 80}}
 >
  <TabBarComponent {...props} />
 </ImageBackground>
</React.Fragment>
```

This worked for me. Spent almost a day figuring out the `<ImageBackground>` thing.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of the 'react-navigation-tabs' the above solutions don't work, what we need to do is, we should pass the following three properties to the `BottomTabBar` component explicitly:

```
 <BottomTabBar
    {...this.props}
    getButtonComponent={this.getButtonComponent}
    getAccessibilityRole={() => 'button'}
    getAccessibilityStates={({focused}) => (focused ? ['selected'] : [])}
  />
```

So the full code for this example is as follows :

```
 class TabBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BottomTabBar
        {...this.props}
        getButtonComponent={this.getButtonComponent}
        getAccessibilityRole={() => 'button'}
        getAccessibilityStates={({focused}) => (focused ? ['selected'] : [])}
      />
    );
  }

  getButtonComponent({route}) {
    if (route.key === 'Other') {
      return () => <View />; // a view that doesn't render its children
    } else {
      return null; // use the default nav button component
    }
  }
}

  const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
      home: {
        screen: Home_StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: 'home',
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <FontAwesome name="home" size={23} color={tintColor} />
          ),
        }),
      },
      favourites: {
        screen: Favourites_StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: 'favourites',
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Ionicons name="md-star" size={25} color={tintColor} />
          ),
        }),
      },
      calendar: {
        screen: Calendar_StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: 'calendar',
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Feather name="calendar" size={23} color={tintColor} />
          ),
        }),
      },
      shoppingList: {
        screen: ShoppingList_StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: 'shopping List',
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Feather name="shopping-bag" size={23} color={tintColor} />
          ),
        }),
      },
      profile: {
        screen: Profile_StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: 'profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Feather name="user" size={23} color={tintColor} />
          ),
        }),
      },
    },
    {
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      swipeEnabled: false,
      animationEnabled: true,
      tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        activeTintColor: Colors.DARK.ICON_ACTIVE,
        inactiveTintColor: Colors.DARK.ICON_INACTIVE,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
        labelStyle: {
          textAlign: 'center',
          fontSize: 10,
          textTransform: 'capitalize',
          color: Colors.DARK.ICON_INACTIVE,
          marginBottom: 1,
          width: 70,
        },
        indicatorStyle: {
          borderBottomColor: Colors.DARK.ICON_INACTIVE,
          borderBottomWidth: 2,
        },
      },
      tabBarComponent: (props) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <ImageBackground
              source={require('../../assets/images/image_bottom.jpg')}
              style={{width: '100%', height: 60}}>
              <TabBar {...props} />
            </ImageBackground>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      },
    },
  );
```